# How to populate a winform chart with a stored procedure in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, stored-procedures, charts

I got a stored procedure which gives me a type and the quantity on how many times this is used.

If I use this in a report, then everything works perfectly.
[image]

My stored procedure looks like this:
[image]

With the following outcome:
[image]

However if I want to use this stored procedure to populate my winform chart, it goes wrong.

I create my datasource, link this to the chart, and then go to the series collection, but there the X and Y values are empty.
[image]
[image]

I tried to manually add them:

```
    Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "TypeSoort"
    Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "QTYTypeSoort"
```

But then I get an error message:

[image]

When I use a normal sql table, then everything works.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like? Are the datatypes of the selected  fields a number or date?

Comment: I have added my stored procedure to the thread + the outcome.  
Now I see a return value of 0.  How can I alter this, so it takes the results of the SP?

Comment: You should go step by step. First one is getting the result of your stored procedure in any typed collection (It would mostly be a DataTable of ADO.Net Dataset, a list(Of SomeEntityFromEntityFramework or my own DataObjectMess). The second one is binding this collection to the Chart Control (or any other controls in fact...).